# How to get contacts for the particular user in Netsuite using RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite

The administrator is having 10 contacts. One of the user has 15 contacts. When i get single contact using RESTlet , Output came. But when i get all contacts it could not fetch all contacts. Its trying to get contacts of administrator.

User should not access the administrator account's contacts. It is showing error like this,

> [code] => INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION
>
> [message] => For security reasons, only an administrator is allowed to edit an administrator record.

i) I want to get all records which is not related to administrator account .

ii) I want to get all my records only which is not related to any account .

### Coding

```
function getAllIDs(datain) {
        var MAX_SIZE = typeof (datain.size) == 'undefined' ? 200 : datain.size;
        var INDEX = 0;
    
        if (typeof (datain.index) !== 'undefined') {
            INDEX = datain.index * MAX_SIZE;
            MAX_SIZE += INDEX;
        }
    
        var NS_filters = new Array();
    
        var columns = new Array();
        columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('lastmodifieddate').setSort(1);
    
        var search = nlapiCreateSearch(datain.recordtype, NS_filters, columns)
        var results = search.runSearch();
        var records = results.getResults(INDEX, MAX_SIZE);
        return records;
    }
    
    function get_Allrecords(datain) {
        var all_IDs = getAllIDs(datain);
        var len = all_IDs.length;
        var result = new Array();
    
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result[i] = nlapiLoadRecord(all_IDs[i].getRecordType(), all_IDs[i].id)
        }
        return result;
    }
```

### Input

```
$datastring = array('recordtype' => 'contact','size' => 100,'index'=>0);
$data_string = json_encode($datastring);
```

Comment: What do you mean by administrator account? You mean contacts created by admin should be ediable? or you mean the contacts associated on admin's employee record?

Comment: admin can create more employees and contacts. Employee also has login he can also create contacts. When i access the contacts using employee's  RESTlet, i could get individual contacts. And also i can get records by  mentioning the size. But when i try to get all records , i am getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on chat discussion

> 1) you do not want to set execute as Role Administrator 
>   2) issue is for contacts that has company field pointing to customers/partners.

The error is not due to RESTlet or script but, more due to restriction on the current user's role on the selected company of contact's record value.

Note that the restrictions may be because of:

> 1) Department, class and Location (Department, class, location restriction on role)
>   2) Based on settings on role few employees have access to only those customers whom you are a sales rep of (Employee Restrictions on role)

Comment: are you trying to update contacts or contact role ? Also, please add your code snippet in the question itself.

Comment: just i want to get one user's contacts. Here before i selected all roles and all employees. After saying your answer , i changed to my role and to me (Employee) in Deployment. But not working

Comment: Whats the value in `Execute as Role` ?